# How to save image to folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using webservice to call method in businesslogics(one class written in vb).I am getting inputppath and path to where i have to save image in that method.I have to create thumbnail and also i have to save original image.Means i want to save masterimage in one folder and its thumnail in different folder. I used following code

```
Public Function CreateThumbNails(ByVal intWidth As Integer, ByVal strInputFilePath As String, ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal strOutputFilePath As String) As String
            Dim lnWidth As Integer = intWidth
            Dim lnHeight As Integer = 100
            Dim bmpOut As System.Drawing.Bitmap = Nothing
            Try
                Dim loBMP As New Bitmap(strInputFilePath)
                Dim lnRatio As Decimal
                Dim lnNewWidth As Integer = 0
                Dim lnNewHeight As Integer = 0
                If loBMP.Width < lnWidth AndAlso loBMP.Height < lnHeight Then
                    lnNewWidth = loBMP.Width
                    lnNewHeight = loBMP.Height
                End If
                If loBMP.Width > loBMP.Height Then
                    lnRatio = CDec(lnWidth) / loBMP.Width
                    lnNewWidth = lnWidth
                    Dim lnTemp As Decimal = loBMP.Height * lnRatio
                    lnNewHeight = CInt(lnTemp)
                Else
                    lnRatio = CDec(lnHeight) / loBMP.Height
                    lnNewHeight = lnHeight
                    Dim lnTemp As Decimal = loBMP.Width * lnRatio
                    lnNewWidth = CInt(lnTemp)
                End If

                ' *** This code creates cleaner (though bigger) thumbnails and properly
                ' *** and handles GIF files better by generating a white background for
                ' *** transparent images (as opposed to black)

                bmpOut = New Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight)
                Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut)
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight)
                g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight)
                loBMP.Dispose()
                bmpOut.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strOutputFilePath) + strFileName)
                bmpOut.Dispose()

                Return strOutputFilePath + strFileName
            Catch e As Exception

                Throw New Exception("ThumbNail Creation Failed")
                Return ""
            End Try
        End Function
```

What code i have to include to save original size image in another folder.Can anybody help?

Comment: Is a method called CreateThumbnails really the right place to be making a copy of the master image? You might want to do that somewhere else (or change the name of the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** trigger happy. you don't need to save it from the bitmap. the file is already there. just copy the file.

If I understand your question then you want to save the image from before you manipulate it to a new location on the server.

That file already exists as a file on the server. The file location of that file is passed into your function as a parameter (strInputFilePath).

The simplest thing to do would to use [File.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) to copy the file to the desired location.

Comment: what code i have to write after disposing to save original image

Comment: A generic error occurred in GDI+.This error is coming in line loBMP.Save(strMyOtherPath).What may be the reason?